# Change location of HelpClient.cfg used for SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, appdata, ssms-2012, roaming-profile

Is it possible to change the location of `%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\HelpLibrary\HelpClient.cfg` to for example, `c:\ssmshelp\HelpClient.cfg` for all users?

The profiles are not saved on my servers, so each time a user starts SQL Management Studio he needs to choose whether he wants to use online or local help. These settings are saved in `Helpclient.cfg` in the local `appdata` folder, but as soon as the user logs off these 'settings' are gone because of the roaming profile structure.